# Using Django with Bootstrap Dynamic Tabs

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

When I use [Bootstrap Dynamic Tabs](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tabs_dynamic&stacked=h) it requires me to use ids in the list anchor tags. Whereas I would rather use a url to a django page like `{% url 'incidents:report' %}`. How can I get it to use the django url and still maintain functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap dynamic tabs work by hiding/displaying inline content within specific divs.  You will need to get that content loaded inline, either through some sort of script (like an AJAX request), or an iframe:

```
<div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
  <iframe style="border:none" src="{% url 'incidents:report' %}"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Are there other/better options bootstrap offers similar to dynamic tabs that doesn't require an AJAX request? Even if I use the request I can't write in `{% block content %} {% endblock content %}` more than once on my base.html.

Comment: I am not aware of another sort of tab from Bootstrap, but the iframe solution requires no AJAX requests.  This jsfiddle shows it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/technotarek/ybt7r/

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a shot.